# How to pivot only 1 column dynamically, while keeping the rest in place

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I try to dynamically pivot a table with 4 columns. 
So far I managed to pivot the column 'AttributeId', however, only the key index 'RefRecId' is shown next to it. I would like to have the other 2 columns to be shown as well.

I wonder where I have to adjust the select statement in order to add the other columns to the result. These columns do not have to be pivoted, just have to be selected the same way as the key (RefRecId).

Below the code so far:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(max) = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Quotename(AttributeId) 
     FROM   SATATTRIBUTEREF       
     FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''); 

DECLARE @maxCols AS NVARCHAR(max) = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', max(' + Quotename(AttributeId) + ') as ' + Quotename(AttributeId)
     FROM   SATATTRIBUTEREF       
     FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''); 

DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(max) =  'SELECT     fat.RefRecId,'+@maxCols+'
                                FROM       (SELECT RefRecId, '+ @cols +'
                                            FROM   SATATTRIBUTEREF 
                                            PIVOT(Max(Value) FOR AttributeId IN ('+ @cols +')) piv) fat


                                group by   fat.RefRecId';

EXECUTE(@query)
```

What am I missing here?

Edit: I had a little blackout, What I am trying to do isn't possible and not necessary either. I'm sorry!
Kind regards,
Igor

Comment: Expected output pls

Comment: Did you try adding those columns to your query and group by?